# How to display array value in group wise in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, lodash

Here In my code `customerSearch` is an array I am getting some value. Now I am trying to map this value in such way like if it display on UI ,it should be in group according to the key.

Like `customer` is a key inside that key there is array and two value is there, so first customer come and bellow that two array value and after that again next key and their values. Same for other key.

```
 customerSearch[
      {
        "key": "customer",
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "John",
            "status": "Active",
            "nationalId": "NBGVH6676"
          },
          { "name": "Abhi",
            "status": "Active",
            "nationalId": "NBGVH6890"}
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "requests",
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Kartik",
            "status": "Active",
            "nationalId": "K0089"
          },
          { "name": "Ashi",
            "status": "Active",
            "nationalId": "AS420"

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "invoice",
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "John",
            "status": "Active",
            "nationalId": "IN998"
          },
          { "name": "Abhi2",
            "status": "Active",
            "nationalId": "ABh007"

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "offering",
        "data": [
          {},
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**Below code in render function**

```
 <View style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5, marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1' }}>
            {this.props.customerSearch.map(
              (data, index) => {
                return (
                  <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5 }} key={index}>
                    <Card>
                      <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', borderBottomColor: '#f1f1f1', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                          <View>
                            <RegularText text={`${data.key}`} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', flexWrap: 'wrap' }} />
                            <SmallText text={` Name ${""}`} textColor="grey" />
                            <SmallText text={` Status ${""}`} textColor="grey" />
                            <SmallText text={` NationalId ${""}`} textColor="grey" />
                          </View>
                        </View>

                      </CardItem>

                    </Card>
                  </View>
                );
              })
            }
          </View>
```

**Example UI display**
Customer
Name
Status
National ID
Name 
Status
National ID

Request
Name 
Status
National ID
Name 
Status
National ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your layout using React Native [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) as below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SectionList, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const customerSearch = [
  {
    "key": "customer",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "status": "Active",
        "nationalId": "NBGVH6676"
      },
      {
        "name": "Abhi",
        "status": "Active",
        "nationalId": "NBGVH6890"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "requests",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Kartik",
        "status": "Active",
        "nationalId": "K0089"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ashi",
        "status": "Active",
        "nationalId": "AS420"

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "invoice",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "status": "Active",
        "nationalId": "IN998"
      },
      {
        "name": "Abhi2",
        "status": "Active",
        "nationalId": "ABh007"

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "offering",
    "data": [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  }
]


export default class Example extends Component {

  renderItems = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{padding: 5}}>
      <Text>{`Name - ${item.name}`}</Text>
      <Text>{`Status - ${item.status}`}</Text>
      <Text>{`NationalId - ${item.nationalId}`}</Text>
    </View>
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
        <SectionList
          sections={customerSearch}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>{section.key}</Text>
          )}
          renderItem={this.renderItems}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Change this according to your requirement.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: if I have to get customerSearch array value in renderItems ,then what approch I should floow ,  I need all key in renderItems fucntion .Please suggest

Comment: ```renderItems = ({ item, section }) => {}``` then you can access key as ```section.key```

Comment: Now I want to make all keys value is card , Now if am using card then all partuclular valie is coming in different card , while I have to disply in .. like if customer key's all value in one card and request all value is 2 then it should come in one card like for all